# Deserialización Json atributo @nil: "true" newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, .net, deserialize, newtonsoft

Estoy deserializando un json, el cual algunos parametros cuando son nulos tiene una propiedad `@nil`, cuando realiza la deserialización genera error, el Json tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
{
    "ArrayOfDatosDetallados": {
        "DatosDetallados": {
            "APELLIDO1": "ARTEA",
            "APELLIDO2": {
                "@nil": "true"
            },
            "DEPTO_DECLA": "NARIÑO (52)",
            "DEPTO_OCU": "NARIÑO (52)",
            "DISCAPACIDAD": "NINGUNA",
            "DOCUMENTO": 67027563,
            "ESTADO_BINARIO": 1,
            "ESTADO_TRANSACCION": "EXITOSA",
            "ETNIA": {
                "@nil": "true"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El proceso que estoy realizando es el siguiente:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VivantoMoviagro>(
      response["ArrayOfDatosDetallados"]["DatosDetallados"].ToString(),
      new JsonSerializerSettings
      {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
      });
```

El error generado es el siguiente:

```
Message: 
    Test method Banagrario.Agrobac.IntegrationTests.VivantoTest.VivantoClientTest.DocumentoVivantoOK threw exception: 
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'ETNIA', line 13, position 12.
  Stack Trace: 
    JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)
    JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()
    JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
    JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
    JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
    JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
    JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
    JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
```

La propiedad `Etnia` es de tipo `string`.

El proceso de deserialización funciona cuando las propiedades Etnia o Apellido2 traen algún valor.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordial saludo,

la solución plantada fué realizar una método de extensión donde se verifica si el dato del `JToken` tiene como propiedad `@nil` para asignar el valor de `null`, y definir una clase que herede de la clase `JsonConverter`, al implementar la clase abstracta utilizamos el método `ReadJson` donde se valida mediante el método de extensión si tiene tal atributo y devolver null.

```
public static partial class JTokenExtensions
{
        public static bool WasNilXmlElement(this JToken token)
        {
            if (token == null)
                return true;
            if (token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
                return true;
            var obj = token as JObject;
            if (obj != null)
            {
                // Check if all properties were translated from XML attributes
                // and one was translated from xsi:nil = true
                // There might be namespaces present as well, e.g.
                // "@xmlns:p3": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                if (obj.Properties().All(p => p.Name.StartsWith("@"))
                    && obj.Properties().Any(p => p.Name == "@nil" || p.Name.EndsWith(":nil") && p.Value.ToString() == "true"))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
}
```

y la clase Converter queda de la siguiente maneja.

```
public class NullableStructConverter<T> : JsonConverter where T : class
{
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(T);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var token = JToken.Load(reader);
            if (token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
                return null;
            if (token.WasNilXmlElement())
                return null;

            return token.ToObject<T>();
        }

        public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

y ya solo nos queda llamar este Converter en nuestro de Deserialización, de la siguiente manera

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entidad>(
                           strJson,
                           new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = { new NullableStructConverter<string>() } });
```

Es importarte especificar al Converter el tipo de dato, para controlar que no se aplique a todas las propiedades del Json. Tambien es una forma de convertir el Converter como atributo y especificarlo a nivel de las propiedades en la entidad.

Si tienen una solución más sencilla me gustaria conocerla.